# "must be an array type but is resolved to char" Tic Tac Toe Program Error

Tags: java, arrays, casting, char

So, I'm creating a tic tac toe program according to the instructions provide to me. Looks like most of the code is complete except i'm getting an unusual error when compiled.

"array required, but char found" when compiled on all lines that start with  "placeHolder"

eg:-  placeHolder[1][0] = 'X';

Can anyone help?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TurtleTicTacToe {
private static char[] placeHolder = new char[9];
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
World w = new World();
Turtle t = new Turtle(w);
drawTicTacToeboard(t);

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
  placeHolder[i] = ' ';
}


int goesFirst = (int) (Math.random()*2);
if (goesFirst == 0)
{
  int computerPick = (int) (Math.random()*9);
  while (placeHolder[computerPick] != ' ')
  {
    computerPick = (int) (Math.random()*9);
  }
  drawOat(t, computerPick);
}
else
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      if (placeHolder[i] == ' ')

      System.out.println("Pick a spot on the tic-tac-toe board between 0-8: ");
      int pick = scanner.nextInt();

      drawXat(t, pick);
    }
  }
}

}

public static void drawTicTacToeboard(Turtle t)
{
t.setPenWidth(4);
t.setPenColor(Color.black);
t.penUp();
t.moveTo(80, 180);
t.penDown();
t.setHeading(90);
t.forward(480);
t.penUp();
t.moveTo(80, 300);
t.penDown();
t.forward(480);
t.penUp();
t.moveTo(240, 60);
t.setHeading(180);
t.penDown();
t.forward(360);
t.penUp();
t.moveTo(400, 60);
t.penDown();
t.forward(360);
}

public static void drawXat(Turtle t, int pick)
{
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

if (pick == 1)
{
 x = 160;
  placeHolder[1][0] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 2)
{
  x = 320;
  placeHolder[2][0] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 3)
{
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[0][1] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 4)
{
  x = 160;
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[1][1] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 5)
{
  x = 320;
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[2][1] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 6)
{
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[0][2] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 7)
{
  x = 160;
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[1][2] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 8)
{
  x = 320;
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[2][2] = 'X';
}

else
{
  placeHolder[0][0] = 'X';
}

    t.setPenWidth(2);
    t.setPenColor(Color.blue);
    t.penUp();
    t.moveTo(90+x, 70+y);
    t.penDown();
    t.moveTo(230+x, 170+y);
    t.penUp();
    t.moveTo(90+x, 170+y);
    t.penDown();
    t.moveTo(230+x, 70+y);
}

public static void drawOat(Turtle t, int AI)
{
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

if (AI == 1)
{
  x = 160;
  placeHolder[1][0] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 2)
{
  x = 320;
  placeHolder[2][0] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 3)
{
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[0][1] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 4)
{
  x = 160;
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[1][1] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 5)
{
  x = 320;
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[2][1] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 6)
{
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[0][2] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 7)
{
  x = 160;
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[1][2] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 8)
{
  x = 320;
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[2][2] = 'O';
}

else 
{
  placeHolder[0][0] = 'O';
}

t.setPenWidth(2);
t.setPenColor(Color.red);
t.penUp();
t.moveTo(90+x, 100+y);
t.setHeading(180);
t.penDown();
t.forward(40);
t.moveTo(140+x, 170+y);
t.setHeading(90);
t.forward(40);
t.moveTo(230+x, 140+y);
t.setHeading(0);
t.forward(40);
t.moveTo(180+x, 70+y);
t.setHeading(270);
t.forward(40);
t.moveTo(90+x, 100+y);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think `placeHolder[1][0]` means?  That isn't a 2D array.

Comment: I thought that's how you write a 2D array,  myArray[i][j] = 0;

Comment: How do you think we will right it then?

Comment: That is how you use a 2D array, but it only works if the thing you're using actually _is_ a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make placeHolder 2D array if you're going to use it as one.

```
private static char[][] placeHolder = new char[9][];
```

Comment: what should I change on the code so that once the user enters a value computer can generate a "0" on the grid

Comment: right now user values show up on the grid, but not what computer picks.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `placeHolder[1][0]` as 2D array But you declared it 1D array `private static char[] placeHolder = new char[9];`.

declare it as 2D array:
`private static char[][] placeHolder = new char[9];`

and also change

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    placeHolder[i] = ' ';
}
```

**TO**

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
     {
           if (placeHolder[i][j] == ' ')
     } 
  }
```

**And also change**

```
if (placeHolder[i] == ' ') to if (placeHolder[i][j] == ' ')
```

Comment: your a huge lifesaver!!!!! Thanks man. Everything compiles and me being the user can enter a number on the interactions pane and it will show up on the tic tac toe grid, problem is computer is not generation the responses to each move.  What do I do with `code` while (placeHolder[computerPick] != ' ') `code` maybe that's where the problem is ??

Comment: @mat I think, you are not checking whether pick is empty or not before calling drawXat(t, pick); instead you are doing OPPOSITE first you are checking cell is empty or not then after you taking input from user i.e. pick. IMO you first take input then check whether it is empty or not and If it is empty then go to drawXat(t,pick) otherwise take again input.

Comment: ok i think i'm understanding what your saying. and I did what you said a little while ago and it wasn't working for me properly. Can you add a new post like the one above and post exactly what your saying??? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you have declared the `placeHolder` as a single dimensional array while you are using it as 2 dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

The global variable placeHolder you are using should be used either as [9] 1D array or [3][3] 2D array not both.

Edit:-

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TurtleTicTacToe {
private static char[][] placeHolder = new char[3][3];
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
World w = new World();
Turtle t = new Turtle(w);
drawTicTacToeboard(t);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
  placeHolder[i][j] = ' ';
}


int goesFirst = (int) (Math.random()*2);
if (goesFirst == 0)
{
  int computerPick = (int) (Math.random()*9);
  while (placeHolder[computerPick/3][computerPick%3] != ' ')
  {
    computerPick = (int) (Math.random()*9);
  }
  drawOat(t, computerPick);
}
else
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      if (placeHolder[i][j] == ' ')

      System.out.println("Pick a spot on the tic-tac-toe board between 0-8: ");
      int pick = scanner.nextInt();

      drawXat(t, pick);
    }
  }
}

}

public static void drawTicTacToeboard(Turtle t)
{
    t.setPenWidth(4);
    t.setPenColor(Color.black);
    t.penUp();
    t.moveTo(80, 180);
    t.penDown();
    t.setHeading(90);
    t.forward(480);
    t.penUp();
    t.moveTo(80, 300);
    t.penDown();
    t.forward(480);
    t.penUp();
    t.moveTo(240, 60);
    t.setHeading(180);
    t.penDown();
    t.forward(360);
    t.penUp();
    t.moveTo(400, 60);
    t.penDown();
    t.forward(360);
}

public static void drawXat(Turtle t, int pick)
{
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

if (pick == 1)
{
 x = 160;
  placeHolder[1][0] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 2)
{
  x = 320;
  placeHolder[2][0] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 3)
{
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[0][1] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 4)
{
  x = 160;
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[1][1] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 5)
{
  x = 320;
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[2][1] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 6)
{
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[0][2] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 7)
{
  x = 160;
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[1][2] = 'X';
}

else if (pick == 8)
{
  x = 320;
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[2][2] = 'X';
}

else
{
  placeHolder[0][0] = 'X';
}

    t.setPenWidth(2);
    t.setPenColor(Color.blue);
    t.penUp();
    t.moveTo(90+x, 70+y);
    t.penDown();
    t.moveTo(230+x, 170+y);
    t.penUp();
    t.moveTo(90+x, 170+y);
    t.penDown();
    t.moveTo(230+x, 70+y);
}

public static void drawOat(Turtle t, int AI)
{
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

if (AI == 1)
{
  x = 160;
  placeHolder[1][0] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 2)
{
  x = 320;
  placeHolder[2][0] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 3)
{
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[0][1] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 4)
{
  x = 160;
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[1][1] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 5)
{
  x = 320;
  y = 120;
  placeHolder[2][1] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 6)
{
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[0][2] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 7)
{
  x = 160;
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[1][2] = 'O';
}

else if (AI == 8)
{
  x = 320;
  y = 240;
  placeHolder[2][2] = 'O';
}

else 
{
  placeHolder[0][0] = 'O';
}

t.setPenWidth(2);
t.setPenColor(Color.red);
t.penUp();
t.moveTo(90+x, 100+y);
t.setHeading(180);
t.penDown();
t.forward(40);
t.moveTo(140+x, 170+y);
t.setHeading(90);
t.forward(40);
t.moveTo(230+x, 140+y);
t.setHeading(0);
t.forward(40);
t.moveTo(180+x, 70+y);
t.setHeading(270);
t.forward(40);
t.moveTo(90+x, 100+y);
}
}`
```

Comment: This code works except for one major problem, The computer does not make the first move and the moves after. ONLY THE USER ENTERED valued appear on the grid.